# rpm jdk-7-linux-x64.rpm

Tags: centos, java, rpm

I tried to install `java 1.7` with `rpm` but got this error:

```
#rpm -i jdk-7-linux-x64.rpm. 
    package jdk-2000:1.7.0-fcs.x86_64 is already installed
```

If the package really was installed, then how come I still can't use `java` or `javac` command. Where is the package installed to?

Thanks

Comment: You need to specify the JAVA_HOME env variable. Try to find out where you install java, then export JAVA_HOME=<install path of java>

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question: "Where is the package installed to", try having RPM list the files in the package:

```
$ rpm -ql jdk-2000:1.7.0-fcs.x86_64
```